# How to keep storage bucket synced with Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

**Question:**

Does Google automatically update storage buckets with changes pushed to a project's Cloud Source Repository?

**Example:**

I create a Google Cloud Platform project called **Cooking** and store the file **recipe.txt** in a bucket.

I modify **recipe.txt** and push the changes from my local master branch to the Cloud Source Repository for **Cooking**.

When I look at the Source Code panel for my project, I see **recipe.txt** is up-to-date with my latest changes.

When I look at the storage bucket for my project, I see **recipe.txt** is not up-to-date (i.e. not in sync with the project's Cloud Source Repository).

Answer (score 3):

No. Google Cloud Source Repositories can be configured to stay in sync with other git repository services, such as GitHub or Bitbucket, but there is no relationship between Google Cloud Source Repository repositories and GCS buckets.

Answer (score 1):

While the question differs from the heading, I will answer how to keep the Cloud Storage bucket in sync with the Cloud Source Repository.

This is possible by using [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build). Create a build trigger for when there was a push to your master branch (or whatever other event, see the Cloud Build docs).

Assuming the path to the folder containing `recipe.txt` inside the Cloud Source Repository is `./path/to/folder` and you want to sync the contents of that folder with the bucket `your-bucket`, use the following `yaml` build config:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      - rsync
      - '-r'
      - '-d'
      - ./path/to/folder
      - 'gs://your-bucket/'
```

(See what `rsync` and it's options are: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)